# Fullcalendar with Angular 8 changing css properties

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am strugling trying to customize the fullcalendar in Angular 8, after lot of problems installing it. i finally have my calendar working but now i pretend to customize it and put some colors in the background... but i don't find the way to edit the css.

As in the official website mention, i am accessing to the fullcalendar API..

```
  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;

  someMethod() {
    let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
}
```

But for example.. how can i change the background-color in the entire calendar?

Comment: check this angular 6 calendar library specific to angular framework that is customizable https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Comment: i tried it... i am going to open a issue, i think is not supported in Angular 8, i had some problems with date-fns

Comment: I am using this calendar in Angular 8 Application.

Comment: huh... i am following the manual step by step. npm install --save angular-calendar date-fns. And then @import "../node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css";

Comment: did you install anything else?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/calendar-utils/date-adapters/date-fns/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/add_days/index' in 'C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\devFolder\ExMed\node_modules\calendar-utils\date-adapters\date-fns'

Comment: Try installing V0.27.0 and check its working.

Comment: i have "angular-calendar": "^0.27.18", and "date-fns": "^2.0.1",

Comment: try downgrading the version and check. "angular-calendar": "0.27.0", and "date-fns": "1.29.0"

Comment: huh it seems to be working! thank man!!